# getting strange result in loops c++

Tags: c++

I wrote a pretty simple code. And it works fine, but why I got A1A2A3 -1102135405. when the correct result is 3192831891

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
        for (int a = 41840; a <= 41849; ++a) {
          for (int b = 37960; b <= 37967; ++b) {
            for (int c = 0; c <= 1; ++c) {
                for (int d = 0; d <= 1; ++d) {
                        int aa = pow(a, 2);
                        int bb = pow(b, 2);
                        int cc = pow(c, 2);
                        int dd = pow(d, 2);
                        int A1 = aa+bb+cc+dd;
                        if (A1 == 3192831891){
                            /*ofstream myfile;
                            myfile.open ("result-factor.txt");
                            myfile <<  "a " << a << "\n";
                            myfile <<  "b " << b << "\n";
                            myfile <<  "c " << c << "\n";
                            myfile <<  "d " << d << "\n";
                            myfile <<  "A1 " << A1 << "\n";
                            myfile << "===================\n";*/
                            cout  <<  "a " << a << "\n";
                            cout  <<  "b " << b << "\n";
                            cout  <<  "c " << c << "\n";
                            cout  <<  "d " << d << "\n";
                            cout  <<  "A1 " << A1 << "\n";
                            cout  << "==========" << "\n";
                            break;
                        }
               }
            }
          }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to all who can clarify that.

UPD: the code edited. just A1=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2

Comment: hi, perhaps step through in a debugger

Comment: This is not a "simple code", this is really bad code. It's hard to read and understand what it's doing or what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Are these variables intended to cause pain and suffering? Please, use names that have *some* meaning. Using `a`, `b`, `c` would be *way* better than whatever mess this is.

Comment: And please take some time to go back to your text-book or tutorial or class-notes, and read about the ranges of 32-bit signed integers. Any decent book, tutorial or class should have information about the typical ranges of values for `int`.

Comment: I've voted to close as "needing details or clarity" since the code is constructed for unreadability.    If you have a problem and seek help, the onus is on YOU to ask the question in a clear manner, that allows people to address the actual problem rather than grappling with code written in a manner incomprehensible to most humans.

Comment: A point about squaring integers: Compilers are smart and getting smarter, but it's almost always faster and safer to multiply integers out rather than `pow` them. `pow` operates on floating point numbers and floating point numbers are imprecise. You often slightly corrupt the data moving integer->floating point->integer because the floating point number couldn't properly represent the integer at some point in the computation.

Comment: thank you, guys. as I said I'm a noob in that. @Someprogrammerdude thanks.

Comment: @Peter I understand you got a bad day today. It's fine. I've edited the code. Have a nice day.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you, dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like integer overflow. int is signed and 32 bits by default, which means the maximum positive number it can hold is 2^31 - 1, which is approximately 2 billion. Your number is larger than that. Larger values become negative in 2's complement, which is why you are seeing a negative number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

I suggest either using a double (double precision float), or using a 64 bit integer if you need integers.

Comment: thank you. But my number is 10 digits. 10 bits?! or not? and it working fine. I got the correct result for a,b,c,d. just A1 is -XXXXX. not sure why.

Comment: A decimal digit takes more than one bit. A bit is base 2. So, a decimal digit takes log(10) / log(2) = 3.3219 bits. Thus the largest 10 digit number (9999999999) would require 34 bits to represent. A signed 32 bit integer can represent only 31 bits worth of positive values.

Comment: thanks a lot again.

Comment: Side note: It's only recently (Like this year) that C++ guaranteed two's complement representation.

Comment: `int` is also not 32-bits by default. The standard only guarantees it can represent a range no smaller than `-32677` to `32767`.  It is true that a fair proportion of modern compilers provide a 32-bit `int`.  There are real-world compilers that supply a 16-bit `int` and a few that support a 64-bit `int`.  In the past when *most* compilers only supported 16-bit `int`, some projections claimed a 32-bit `int` was unlikely to be common - and such projections, with time, turned out to be false. Similarly, projections that future compilers will still mostly support a 32-bit `int` may be proven false

Comment: At the very least you'll get insane name sprawl. I don't think  `long long long long long` for a 512 bit integer would be tolerated for very long.